# React Redux Class Component TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I get the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')**

so I try to get data detail users using `id`, and when I try to see, I get the error

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Jumbotron from './component/Jumbotron'
import NavbarComponent from './component/NavbarComponent'

import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";

import HomeContainer from './container/HomeContainer';
import CreateUserContainer from './container/CreateUserContainer';
import EditUserContainer from './container/EditUserContainer';
import DetailUserContainer from './container/DetailUserContainer';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <NavbarComponent />
          <Jumbotron />
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<HomeContainer/>} exact />
            <Route path='/create' element={<CreateUserContainer />} exact />
            <Route path='/edit/:id' element={<EditUserContainer />} exact />
            <Route path='/detail/:id' element={<DetailUserContainer />} exact />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**container/DetailUserContainer.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getDetailUser } from '../actions/UserAction';

class DetailUserContainer extends Component {
  
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.dispatch(getDetailUser(this.props.match.params.id));
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container className='pt-3'>
          <div>
            <h1>Detail</h1>
          </div>
        </Container>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect()(DetailUserContainer)
```

**reducers/users.js**

```
import { GET_LIST_USERS, GET_DETAIL_USERS } from "../actions/UserAction";

let initialState = {
    getUsers: false,
    errorGetUser: false,
    // DETAIL USER
    getDetailUsers: false,
    errorGetDetailUser: false
}

const users = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_LIST_USERS:
            return {
                ...state,
                getUsers: action.payload.data,
                errorGetUser: action.payload.errorMessage
            };
        case GET_DETAIL_USERS:
            return {
                ...state,
                getDetailUsers: action.payload.data,
                errorGetDetailUser: action.payload.errorMessage
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default users;
```

**actions/UserAction.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export const GET_LIST_USERS = "GET_LIST_USERS"
export const GET_DETAIL_USERS = "GET_DETAIL_USERS"

// GET USER
export const getListUser= () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/baihaqiyazid/database/users')
      .then(function (response) {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_LIST_USERS,
          payload: {
            data: response.data,
            errorMessage: false
          }
        })
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_LIST_USERS,
          payload: {
            data: false,
            errorMessage: error.message
          }
        })
      })
  }
}

// DETAIL USER
export const getDetailUser= (id) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/baihaqiyazid/database/users/' + id)
      .then(function (response) {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_DETAIL_USERS,
          payload: {
            data: response.data,
            errorMessage: false
          }
        })
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_DETAIL_USERS,
          payload: {
            data: false,
            errorMessage: error.message
          }
        })
      })
  }
}
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import users from './users'

export default combineReducers({
    users
})
```

How to solve it?

Comment: there is no  params named as match  for your Detail user Component..

Comment: yeah, I am beginner redux, how to solve it? I has edited the post

Answer (score 0):

In your component did mount use this..

```
componentDidMount(){
    // @id params
    this.props.getDetailUser(1);
  }
```

Also connect your state using mapstate..

```
function mapState(state) {
  return {
    match: state.users // which is the name you have assigned in the combine Reducer
  };
}

export default connect(mapState, {getDetailUser})(DashBoard);
```

refer..
[Class component with Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280599/class-component-with-redux)

https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/connect

Comment: I try this add function mapState like that, and also connect, but the result still the same

Comment: could you please give the details of your combineReducer ?

Comment: yes, I has edited the post

Comment: your getDetailUser action requires an id input .. what was the id you are trying to send ? as far i seen there is no id in your code..

Comment: in actions/users.js `export const getDetailUser= (id)`

Comment: that id is the param which needed for that function... what you are tring to send the params.. if you are just want it to work .. pass any params 1 or 2 in the component did mount...

Answer (score 0):

Before **version 6**, react-router-dom's `Route` components passed a few routing properties to any component it rendered, for example you had a route like this:

```
  <Route path='/' component={HomeContainer} exact />
```

You had access to route props inside `HomeContainer`, like this:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

In the above line, `match` is one of route props, passed from `Route` down to `HomeContainer`.

After **Version 6**, (which you are using), no such thing happens. The route props are no longer passed down to children, so you don't have access to `this.props.match`, or other route props (`location`, etc...).

Instead, you need to use hooks in order to have access to `match`, which you can't use inside Class Components. Two solutions are available:

1. If you want to stick to classes, Change `react-router-dom` version from **v6** to **v5**, (then you have to use components like `Route` according to `v5` API).
2. Get rid of Classes, instead use Functional Components, have access to hooks and keep using `react-router-dom` v6.